# Save only parts of the store (sub state) with redux-persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I want to persist only a sub state (`placeOfLiving`) of one of my `reducers`. This is the `reducer` where I want a subset from.

```js
const initialState = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 55,
  placeOfLiving: {
    city: 'Munich',
    zipCode: 1234,
  },
};

function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // handle actions that modify the user state here
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And this is my `redux` setup

```js
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['user'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  settings: settingsReducer
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

How would I only persist and hydrate `placeOfLiving` from the `userReducer`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for this

```
import { getPersistConfig } from 'redux-deep-persist';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  settings: settingsReducer
});

const config = getPersistConfig({
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['user.placeOfLiving'], 
    rootReducer

});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
```